# How do I prevent duplicate NaN entries when generating a histogram?

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

Suppose I have a pandas Series which contains a few NaNs.

```
import pandas as pd
itvl = pd.Interval(left=2.0, right=3.0, closed='right')
srs = pd.Series(data=[itvl, float('nan'), float('nan'), itvl])
```

And I want to generate a histogram...

```
hist = pd.Series(dtype=float)
for row in srs:
    if isinstance(row, float):
        if float("nan") in hist:
            hist.loc[float("nan")] += 1
        else:
            hist.loc[float("nan")] = 1
    else:
        if row in hist:
            hist.loc[row] += 1
        else:
            hist.loc[row] = 1
hist
```

This code produces a histogram that looks like

```
(2.0, 3.0]    2
NaN           1
NaN           1 
dtype: int64
```

Does anyone know how the code could be altered such that it would recognize that the 'NaN' entries should be combined?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `fillna` to replace `NaN` values with a string.

```
srs.fillna('No interval', inplace=True)
```

Comment: When I try that I get an error, ```TypeError: 'IntervalArray.fillna' only supports filling with a scalar 'pandas.Interval'. Got a 'str' instead.```  Any suggestions?

Comment: a workaround would be `srs.fillna(pd.Interval(-np.inf, -np.inf), inplace=True)` ... perhaps a solution would be avoiding those NaNs in the first place, can you edit your question and include the code where you populate that interval series?

Comment: The NaNs are in the original data set.  I believe they typically represent a non-response to a question from the original survey.  In fact my goal in this post was to get some help finding ways to include the NaNs in my analysis.  Instead of imputing them or deleting them I would like to count them.

Comment: All right, that has some implications if you will use any kind of regression/classification or ML algorithm. Interval data is normally considered as ordinal (interval1 is less than interval2), but if you include an "interval NaN" then you must change your data from Interval to [categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html), since interval NaN cannot be compared with inequalities (>, <) and your predictions will probably take a hit for that... but it can be done if you use categoricals instead interval